# Retrieving list of assets in a Content Builder folder using REST API call

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, content-builder, content-assets

I am looking to retrieve a list of all assets within a folder in Content Builder using REST API. 
I have the following endpoint: `/asset/v1/content/categories/XXXXXX` with no body. This returns a 404. I have also tried using a filter like this: `/asset/v1/content/assets?$filter=Category%20eq%20'XXXXXX'`. Any ideas on retrieving Content Blocks in a folder in Content Builder?

Answer (score 2):

You're very nearly there with your second route. The issue you have is you're filtering on "Category eq 'XXXXX'", but the category is an object, not a string. If you know the Id of the category/folder, you construct the filter like so:

```
/asset/v1/content/assets?$page=1&$pagesize=50&$filter=category.id%20eq%2019913
```

If you know the name of the category, you could potentially filter by name:

```
/asset/v1/content/assets?$page=1&$pagesize=50&$filter=category.name%20eq%20MyFolder
```